# RxJs - Calculate & emit values only if there is a subscriber

Tags: rxjs, rxjs5

I want to create an observable that emits file additions/removal (via `chokidar`). I am able to do this by something like this:

```js
Rx.Observable.create((subscriber) => {
  this.watcher = chokidar.watch(
     this.contentPath
  );
  this.watcher.on('addDir', () => { subscriber.next(); });
  this.watcher.on('unlinkDir', () => { subscriber.next(); });
});
```

What I want to do is, I want to **stop** for watching files, **if there is no subscriber** and start again when something subscribes to it. Something like this, but with RxJs:

```js
class Notifier {
  constructor() {
    this.subscriberCount = 0;
  }

  subscribe(onNext, onError, complete) {
    this.subscriberCount++;
    if (this.subscriberCount === 1) {
      this.startInternalWatcher();
    }
    return () => {
      this.subscriberCount--;
      if (this.subscriberCount === 0) {
        this.stopInternalWatcher();
      }
    }
  }
}

// files are not watched
const n = new Notifier();

const s1 = n.subscribe(() => {}) // files are being wacthed
const s2 = n.subscribe(() => {}) // files are being wacthed
s1() // unsubscribed from 1, files are still watched.
s2() // unsubscribed from 2, files are not watched because no one is interested in.
```

I am new to RxJs so I might be missing some obvious solution. Is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're on the right track. First up, if you return a function from the creator [it will be called when the subscription is cancelled](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/create.md), so you can use that to destroy the watcher.

That should solve most of your problem, but if you want to ensure there's a maximum of one "watcher" at one time you can tack on [`refCount`](https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/core/operators/refcount.md):

```
return Rx.Observable.create((subscriber) => {
  this.watcher = chokidar.watch(
     this.contentPath
  );
  this.watcher.on('addDir', () => { subscriber.next(); });
  this.watcher.on('unlinkDir', () => { subscriber.next(); });

  return () => this.watcher.off('addDir unlinkDir');
})
.publish()
.refCount();
```